# error: use of bitwise '|' with boolean operands

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, logical-or

Little update...
The error code come from notcurses.h so can't change that and also
since 3 months I compile without problem but now

when `#include <notcurses/notcurses.h>` I obtain this error !

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/notcurses/3.0.9_1/include/notcurses/notcurses.h:205:12: error: use of bitwise '|' with boolean operands [-Werror,-Wbitwise-instead-of-logical]
  return !(ncchannel_default_p(channel) | ncchannel_palindex_p(channel));
          ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                        ||
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/notcurses/3.0.9_1/include/notcurses/notcurses.h:205:12: note: cast one or both operands to int to silence this warning
1 error generated.
```

I don't think it's related to notcurses itself... but last week, everything was ok.
I came back from a trip with my laptop and when trying to compile, I now have this error.

In notcurses.h the function in error is :

```
201 // Is this channel using RGB color?
202 static inline bool
203 ncchannel_rgb_p(uint32_t channel){
# 204   ***// bitwise or is intentional (allows compiler more freedom)***
205   return !(ncchannel_default_p(channel) | ncchannel_palindex_p(channel));
206 }
```

I tried to update brew, gcc, and notcurses
I use  $(pkg-config --cflags --libs notcurses) in compilation

Is there a way to resolve that without

- modifying notcurses.h
- removing -Werror -Wall -Wextra on compile line

Should I reinstall MacOs ?

Comment: From the error message adding `-Wno-bitwise-instead-of-logical` should do the trick?

Comment: yes, why not, you remove only this particular warning... wouldn't solve completely the problem... but is a good workaround to continue working while searching for resolving the issue !

Comment: you should be able to silence warnings that you have no influence on with the include flag `-isystem path`. This will treat your includes within `path` as system libraries.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Or remove `-Werror`. The code is OK; it's simply a warning. The reason for the  warning is not entirely clear to me since the result (for non-side-effect arguments) is identical.

Answer (score 3):

notcurses author here. i wish you would have brought this to our bugtracker; it would have been addressed months ago! we're handling it right now as part of https://github.com/dankamongmen/notcurses/pull/2746

Comment: what should the reader of this answer post do with this info? any workarounds? just wait patiently? would be nice to spell out anything actionable.

Comment: the fix went in yesterday. you can wait for a new release, sync to head of master (or to d0ae40415228871c68fc9cebe6a7f9ef0f476082 anyway), or lift the recent commits.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest fix, without investigating into bitmask optimisation is to convert the boolean predicate function return value to `int` as suggested by the compiler:

```
// Is this channel using RGB color?
static inline bool ncchannel_rgb_p(uint32_t channel) {
   // bitwise or is intentional (allows compiler more freedom)
   return !(+ncchannel_default_p(channel) | +ncchannel_palindex_p(channel));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One could replace the

```
205   return !(ncchannel_default_p(channel) | ncchannel_palindex_p(channel));
```

with

```
205   return !(!(channel & NC_BGDEFAULT_MASK) | (channel & (NC_BGDEFAULT_MASK | NC_BG_PALETTE))
```

to resolve the warning and to allow the compiler to prevent branching with `||`.